# How to get string value from LocalizedStringKey?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm localizing my SwiftUI app with using [LocalisedStringKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/localizedstringkey) and the help of the following code:

```
Text(l10n.helloWorld)
```

Where `l10n` is:

```
enum l10n {
   internal static let helloWorld = LocalizedStringKey("hello.world")
}
```

Where `"hello.world"` is defined in the file `Localizable.strings`:

```
"hello.world" = "Hello world !";
```

While this code works in SwiftUI's `View` like this:

```
...
Text(i18n.helloWorld)
...
```

I can't find a way to get l10n value from `LocalizedStringKey` in code behind like this:

```
l10n.helloWorld.toString()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because SwiftUI is not mean't to do localization from code behind, all localization must happen in view declaration.

However there's a way to achieve that via extensions methods :

```
extension LocalizedStringKey {

    /**
     Return localized value of thisLocalizedStringKey
     */
    public func toString(arguments: CVarArg...) -> String {
        //use reflection
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        
        //try to find 'key' attribute value
        let attributeLabelAndValue = mirror.children.first { (arg0) -> Bool in
            let (label, _) = arg0
            if(label == "key"){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        
        if(attributeLabelAndValue != nil) {
            //ask for localization of found key via NSLocalizedString
            return String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(attributeLabelAndValue!.value as! String, comment: ""), arguments);
        }
        else {
            return "Swift LocalizedStringKey signature must have changed. @see Apple documentation."
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly you must use `Reflection` to achieve that as `key` has an `internal` level of protection in `LocalizedStringKey`, use at your own risks.

Use asis :

```
let s = l10n.helloWorld.toString();
```

Comment: Calling `String.localizedStringWithFormat(_:_)` like this is unsafe. `LocalizedStringKey` supports interpolation and formatting. So if someone tries the code above with `"Hello, \("world)!"`, they can get `"Hello, (null)!"` (and I think that's the lucky case; the worst case would be a crash).

Answer (score -1):

little bit updated answer of Marc_Alx

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@available(macOS 10.15, *)
@available(iOS 15, *)
public extension LocalizedStringKey {
    func localizedStr(_ args: [CVarArg]? = nil ) -> String {
        //use reflection
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        
        //try to find 'key' attribute value
        let attributeLabelAndValue = mirror.children.first { (arg0) -> Bool in
            let (label, _) = arg0
            
            return label == "key"
        }
        
        if attributeLabelAndValue != nil {
            if let args = args {
                return String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(attributeLabelAndValue!.value as! String, comment: ""), args )
            }
            
            //ask for localization of found key via NSLocalizedString
            return String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(attributeLabelAndValue!.value as! String, comment: ""))
        } else {
            return "Swift LocalizedStringKey signature must have changed. @see Apple documentation."
        }
    }
}

@available(macOS 10.15, *)
@available(iOS 15, *)
public extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return LocalizedStringKey(self).localizedStr()
    }
    
    func localized(params: [String]) -> String {
        return LocalizedStringKey(self).localizedStr(params)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated version from @Marc_Alx with the version that localizes the interpolation arguments automatically.

##### Usage

```swift
let number = 0.2
let localizedStringKey1: LocalizedStringKey = "Hello World \(number)"
let localizedStringKey2: LocalizedStringKey = "Hello World \(number, format: .percent)"

// Prints "Hello World 0.2"
print(localizedStringKey1.localized)
// Limitation: Prints "Hello World 0.2" instead of "Hello World 20%"
print(localizedStringKey2.localized)
```

##### Limitation

The format in `"\(value, format:)"` interpolation format is ignored and replaced by a `String(describing:)` value

##### Implementation

```swift
public extension LocalizedStringKey {

    private typealias FArgs = (CVarArg, Formatter?)
    
    /// Returns the localized value of this `LocalizedStringKey` using reflection.
    /// - Important: SwiftUI `format` for interpolated values is ignored.
    var localized: String? {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        let key: String? = mirror.descendant("key") as? String
        
        guard let key else {
            return nil
        }
        
        var fargs: [FArgs] = []
        
        if let arguments = mirror.descendant("arguments") as? Array<Any> {
            for argument in arguments {
                let argumentMirror = Mirror(reflecting: argument)
                
                if let storage = argumentMirror.descendant("storage") { 
                    let storageMirror = Mirror(reflecting: storage)
                    
                    if let formatStyleValue = storageMirror.descendant("formatStyleValue") {
                        let formatStyleValueMirror = Mirror(reflecting: formatStyleValue)

                        guard var input = formatStyleValueMirror.descendant("input") as? CVarArg else {
                            continue
                        }
                        
                        let formatter: Formatter? = nil
                        
                        // TODO: Create relevant formatters
                        if let _ = formatStyleValueMirror.descendant("format") {
                            // Cast input to String
                            input = String(describing: input) as CVarArg
                        }
                        
                        fargs.append((input, formatter))
                    } else if let storageValue = storageMirror.descendant("value") as? FArgs {
                        fargs.append(storageValue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Optionally, pass SwiftUI `bundle` here
        let string = NSLocalizedString(key, comment: "")
        
        if mirror.descendant("hasFormatting") as? Bool ?? false {
            return String.localizedStringWithFormat(
                string, 
                fargs.map { arg, formatter in
                    formatter?.string(for: arg) ?? arg
                }
            )
        } else {
            return string
        }
    }
}
```